# ImportError: libjpeg.so.9: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: python, matplotlib, importerror

I try to import matplotlib and then later skimage.io and I get some issues with that. What do I have to do?

```
import matplotlib

ImportError: 
    Could not load requested Qt binding. Please ensure that
    PyQt4 >= 4.7 or PySide >= 1.0.3 is available,
    and only one is imported per session.
    Currently-imported Qt library:   None
    PyQt4 installed:                 False
    PyQt5 installed:                 True
    PySide >= 1.0.3 installed:       True
    Tried to load:                   ['pyqtdefault']

matplotlib.use('QT5Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from ggplot import *

import numpy as np
from scipy import stats
from pandas import DataFrame
import pandas as pd
import cv2
import os
from  itertools import chain

import skimage.io

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "[...]/PyCharm/pycharm-community-2016.3.2/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "[...]/anaconda2/envs/saliency/lib/python2.7/site-packages/skimage/io/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .manage_plugins import *
  File "[...]/PyCharm/pycharm-community-2016.3.2/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "[...]/anaconda2/envs/saliency/lib/python2.7/site-packages/skimage/io/manage_plugins.py", line 28, in <module>
    from .collection import imread_collection_wrapper
  File "[...]/PyCharm/pycharm-community-2016.3.2/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "[...]/anaconda2/envs/saliency/lib/python2.7/site-packages/skimage/io/collection.py", line 12, in <module>
    from PIL import Image
  File "[...]/PyCharm/pycharm-community-2016.3.2/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "[...]/anaconda2/envs/saliency/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 67, in <module>
    from PIL import _imaging as core
  File "[...]/PyCharm/pycharm-community-2016.3.2/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
ImportError: libjpeg.so.9: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Here are my installed packages from `conda list`:

```
backports                 1.0                      py27_0    defaults
backports-abc             0.5                       <pip>
backports.shutil-get-terminal-size 1.0.0                     <pip>
backports.ssl-match-hostname 3.4.0.2                   <pip>
backports_abc             0.5                      py27_0    defaults
beautifulsoup4            4.3.2                     <pip>
bleach                    1.5.0                    py27_0    defaults
brewer2mpl                1.4.1                    py27_2    conda-forge
cairo                     1.12.18                       6    defaults
certifi                   2017.1.23                py27_0    conda-forge
configparser              3.5.0                    py27_0    defaults
coursera                  0.0.3                     <pip>
cycler                    0.10.0                   py27_0    defaults
dbus                      1.10.10                       0    defaults
decorator                 4.0.11                   py27_0    defaults
entrypoints               0.2.2                    py27_1    defaults
enum34                    1.1.6                    py27_0    defaults
expat                     2.1.0                         0    defaults
fontconfig                2.11.1                        6    defaults
freetype                  2.5.5                         2    defaults
functools32               3.2.3.2                  py27_0    defaults
get_terminal_size         1.0.0                    py27_0    defaults
gettext                   0.19.7                        1    conda-forge
ggplot                    0.11.5                   py27_1    conda-forge
glib                      2.50.2                        1    defaults
graphite2                 1.3.9                         0    conda-forge
gst-plugins-base          1.8.0                         0    defaults
gstreamer                 1.8.0                         0    defaults
harfbuzz                  0.9.39                        1    defaults
html5lib                  0.999                    py27_0    defaults
icu                       54.1                          0    defaults
ipykernel                 4.5.2                    py27_0    defaults
ipython                   5.3.0                    py27_0    defaults
ipython-genutils          0.1.0                     <pip>
ipython_genutils          0.1.0                    py27_0    defaults
ipywidgets                6.0.0                    py27_0    defaults
jbig                      2.1                           0    defaults
jinja2                    2.9.5                    py27_0    defaults
jpeg                      8d                            2    defaults
jsonschema                2.5.1                    py27_0    defaults
jupyter                   1.0.0                    py27_3    defaults
jupyter-client            5.0.0                     <pip>
jupyter-console           5.1.0                     <pip>
jupyter-core              4.3.0                     <pip>
jupyter_client            5.0.0                    py27_0    defaults
jupyter_console           5.1.0                    py27_0    defaults
jupyter_core              4.3.0                    py27_0    defaults
libffi                    3.2.1                         1    defaults
libgcc                    5.2.0                         0    defaults
libgfortran               3.0.0                         1    defaults
libiconv                  1.14                          0    defaults
libpng                    1.6.28                        0    conda-forge
libsodium                 1.0.10                        0    defaults
libtiff                   4.0.6                         3    defaults
libxcb                    1.12                          1    defaults
libxml2                   2.9.4                         0    defaults
markupsafe                0.23                     py27_2    defaults
matplotlib                2.0.0               np112py27_2    conda-forge
mistune                   0.7.4                    py27_0    defaults
mkl                       2017.0.1                      0    defaults
nbconvert                 5.1.1                    py27_0    defaults
nbformat                  4.3.0                    py27_0    defaults
networkx                  1.11                     py27_0    defaults
notebook                  4.4.1                    py27_0    defaults
numpy                     1.12.0                   py27_0    defaults
olefile                   0.44                     py27_0    defaults
opencv-python             3.2.0.6                   <pip>
openssl                   1.0.2k                        1    defaults
pandas                    0.19.2              np112py27_1    conda-forge
pandocfilters             1.4.1                    py27_0    defaults
pango                     1.39.0                        0    defaults
path.py                   10.1                     py27_0    defaults
pathlib2                  2.2.0                    py27_0    defaults
patsy                     0.4.1                    py27_0    defaults
pcre                      8.39                          1    defaults
pexpect                   4.2.1                    py27_0    defaults
pickleshare               0.7.4                    py27_0    defaults
pillow                    4.0.0                    py27_1    defaults
pip                       9.0.1                    py27_1    defaults
pixman                    0.32.6                        0    defaults
prompt-toolkit            1.0.13                    <pip>
prompt_toolkit            1.0.13                   py27_0    defaults
ptyprocess                0.5.1                    py27_0    defaults
pyasn1                    0.1.7                     <pip>
pycairo                   1.10.0                   py27_0    defaults
pygments                  2.2.0                    py27_0    defaults
pyparsing                 2.1.4                    py27_0    defaults
pyqt                      5.6.0                    py27_2    defaults
pyside                    1.2.1                    py27_1    defaults
python                    2.7.13                        0    defaults
python-dateutil           2.6.0                    py27_0    defaults
pytz                      2016.10                  py27_0    defaults
pyzmq                     16.0.2                   py27_0    defaults
qt                        5.6.0                         0    defaults
qtconsole                 4.2.1                    py27_1    defaults
readline                  6.2                           2    defaults
requests                  2.7.0                     <pip>
scandir                   1.5                      py27_0    defaults
scikit-image              0.12.3              np112py27_1    defaults
scikit-learn              0.18.1              np112py27_1    defaults
scipy                     0.19.0              np112py27_0    defaults
setuptools                27.2.0                   py27_0    defaults
shiboken                  1.2.1                    py27_0    defaults
simplegeneric             0.8.1                    py27_1    defaults
singledispatch            3.4.0.3                  py27_0    defaults
sip                       4.18                     py27_0    defaults
six                       1.10.0                   py27_0    defaults
sqlite                    3.13.0                        0    defaults
ssl_match_hostname        3.4.0.2                  py27_1    defaults
statsmodels               0.8.0               np112py27_0    defaults
subprocess32              3.2.7                    py27_0    defaults
terminado                 0.6                      py27_0    defaults
testpath                  0.3                      py27_0    defaults
tk                        8.5.18                        0    defaults
tornado                   4.4.2                    py27_0    defaults
traitlets                 4.3.2                    py27_0    defaults
urllib3                   1.10.4                    <pip>
wcwidth                   0.1.7                    py27_0    defaults
wheel                     0.29.0                   py27_0    defaults
widgetsnbextension        2.0.0                    py27_0    defaults
xorg-libxau               1.0.8                         3    conda-forge
xorg-libxdmcp             1.1.2                         3    conda-forge
xz                        5.2.2                         1    defaults
zeromq                    4.1.5                         0    defaults
zlib                      1.2.8                         3    defaults
```

Comment: can you check if you have libjpeg installed?  If you are using something like debian/ubuntu `dpkg --get-selections | grep libjpeg`

Comment: @NickHale: I reinstalled `conda install scikit-image`. Why did that help?

Comment: So, fixed?  I had this issue, but not with anaconda and I fixed it by making sure that the `libjpeg.so.9` folder was in my `/etc/ld.so.conf` and then ran `ldconfig`.  So it could have been an issue with your library path and as libjpeg is a dependency of scikit-image.  Glad its fixed

Comment: @NickHale: Yes it is fixed, but I get these kind of errors all the time and I "solve" them by reinstalling the libraries and with some luck I get the order right... does not feel great.

Answer (score 5):

Make sure that there is the file libjpeg.so.9 under your ..anaconda/lib/ folder. 
If there is older version available, e.g. libjpeg.so.8, then update it with typing in terminal  `conda update -c conda-forge jpeg`

Answer (score 2):

I resolved this with
sudo apt install libjpeg9

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).